# Searching in blogger platform via two label widgets as dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, label, blogger

In the blogger platform, in order to search at the same time two labels, you have to write in url the following:

/search/?q=label:____%20label:____

What if I have two label widgets, the first one is for locations and the second one for the type of corporations, and choosing values from each one, to make above query? Is it possible?
Now, when choosing from the first label widget a label, it starts directly a query....
Just for your information, label widgets have different form, using the following code:

```
 <b:widget id='Label2' locked='false' title='Κατηγορία' type='Label'>
     <b:widget-settings>
       <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'>.....</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showType'>USER_SELECTED</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
     </b:widget-settings>
 <b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title'>
</b:if>
<div class="listsearch-input-item">
<div class='widget-content'>
<select class='chosen-select' onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option>Επέλεξε κατηγορία...</option>
<b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
<option expr:value='data:label.url'><data:label.name/>
(<data:label.count/>)
</option>
</b:loop>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a solution...

```
<b:widget id='Label2' locked='false' title='Κατηγορία' type='Label' version='1'>
     <b:widget-settings>
       <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'>Auto-Moto,Beach Bar,Catering,Έπιπλα,Αθλητικές Δραστηριότητες,Ανθοπωλείο,Ασφαλιστές-Ασφαλιστικές Εταιρείες,Βενζινάδικα,Βιβλιοπωλείο,Γάμος-Βάφτιση,Γραφείο Μεταφορών,Γραφικές Τέχνες,Γυμναστήρια,Δερματολόγοι-Αφροδισιολόγοι,Δημόσιες Υπηρεσίες,Διαιτολόγος-Διατροφολόγος,Διδασκαλία Ελληνικών Παραδοσιακών Χορών,Δικηγόροι-Δικηγορικό Γραφείο,Είδη Δώρου,Είδη υγιεινής,Εκμάθηση Πληροφορικής,Ελαιοχρωματισμοί,Εμπόριο-Επιδιόρθωση Η/Υ,Ενδύματα,Ενεργειακά,Ενοικιαζόμενα Δωμάτια,Επιπλωμένα διαμερίσματα-Studio,Εργαστήριο Ζαχαροπλαστικής,Εστιατόρειο,Ζαχαροπλαστείο,Ιατρεία,Ιδιαίτερα Μαθήματα,Ιταλική Κουζίνα,Ιχθυοπωλεία,Κάβες,Κέντρο Αισθητικής και Αδυνατίσματος,Καθαριότητα,Καρδιολόγος,Κατασκευές-Τέχνη,Καφενείο,Καφετέρια,Κινητή Τηλεφωνία,Κομμωτήριο-Κουρείο,Κοσμηματοπωλεία,Κρεοπωλείο,Κρύο Πιάτο,Κτηνίατροι,Λογιστής-Λογιστικό Γραφείο,ΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΟΣ ΑΥΤΟΚΙΝΗΤΩΝ,Μαιευτήρες-Γυναικολόγοι,Μεζεδοπωλείο-Ουζερί,Μικρογεύματα,Μπαρ,Ξενοδοχείο,Ξυλεία,Ξυλουργικές Εργασίες,Οδοντίατρος,Οπτικά,Οπωροπωλεία,Οφθαλμίατρος,Παιδίατροι,Παιδικά-Βρεφικά,Παραδοσιακά Προϊόντα,Πιτσαρία,Πολυκαταστήματα,Πρακτορεία ΟΠΑΠ,Σουβλατζίδικο-Ψητοπωλείο,Συστήματα Ασφαλείας,Σχολές Χωρού,Ταβέρνα,Τεχνικές-Κατασκευαστικές Εταιρίες,Τουριστικά Είδη,Τράπεζες-ΑΤΜ,Τυπογραφεία,Υδραυλικοί,Υποδήματα,Φαρμακεία,Φούρνοι-Αρτοποιεία,Φροντιστήριο Ξένων Γλωσσών,Φωτογραφείο-Βιντεοσκοπήσεις,Χειρούργοι</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showType'>USER_SELECTED</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
     </b:widget-settings>
     <b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title'>
</b:if>
<div class='listsearch-input-item'>
<div class='widget-content'>
<select class='label2_test' id='chosen-select'>
<option>Επέλεξε κατηγορία...</option>
<b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
<option expr:value='data:label.name'><data:label.name/>
(<data:label.count/>)
</option>
</b:loop>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
   </b:widget>
   <b:widget id='Label1' locked='false' title='Τοποθεσίες' type='Label' version='1'>
     <b:widget-settings>
       <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>ALPHA</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='display'>LIST</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='selectedLabelsList'>Άγιος Ελευθέριος,Άγιος Ιωάννης-Πόρτο,Άγιος Μάρκος,Άγιος Νικόλαος,Άγιος Ρωμανός,Άγιος Σώστης,Άγιος Φωκάς,Αγάπη,Αγία Βαρβάρα,Αγία Κυριακή,Αγία Παρασκευή,Αγκάλη,Αετοφωλιά,Ακτή Έλλης,Ακτή Δρόσου,Ακτή Π.Λιαρούτσου,Αρνάδος,Βάγια,Βάνη,Βίντζι,Βουρνή,Βωλάξ,Γύρλα,Θέση Κόκκινα,Κάμπος,Κάτω Κλείσμα,Κέχρος,Καρδιανή,Καρυά,Κιόνια,Κρόκος,Κτικάδος,Κώμη,Λαούτι,Λεωφόρος Αγκάλης,Λεωφόρος Ζαννάκη Αλαβάνου,Λεωφόρος Μεγαλόχαρης,Λεωφόρος Σταυρού-Κιονίων,Λεωφόρος Τριποτάμου,Μέση,Οδός 25ης Μαρτίου,Οδός Άννης Χατζηιωάννου,Οδός Έλλης,Οδός Α.Μεσσηνέζη,Οδός Αγίου Ιωάννου,Οδός Αλέξανδρου Λαγουρού,Οδός Αντωνίου Σώχου,Οδός Αφών Φιτάλη,Οδός Γ. Λαμπράκη,Οδός Γ.Βουτσινού,Οδός Γ.Γάφου,Οδός Γ.Παλαμάρη,Οδός Γ.Φαλιέρου,Οδός Γιαννούλη Χαλεπά,Οδός Δ. Δρόσου,Οδός Ευαγγελιστρίας,Οδός Ευστρατίου,Οδός Ηλία Γάφου,Οδός Ηρώων Πολυτεχνείου,Οδός Θ.Αφεντούλη,Οδός Ι.Βούλγαρη,Οδός Ι.Κοτσώνη,Οδός Ιωάννη Καρδαμίτση,Οδός Ιωάννη Μεταξά,Οδός Ιωάννου Πλατή,Οδός Κ.Αλαβάνου,Οδός Κ.Τροχάνη,Οδός Καποδιστρίου,Οδός Λάμπρου Κατσώνη,Οδός Μάρκου Κρικελή,Οδός Μαντώς Μαυρογένους,Οδός Μητρ.Γαβριήλ,Οδός Μητρ.Χαλκίδος Νικολάου,Οδός Ν.Γκύζη,Οδός Ν.Κορνάρου,Οδός Ν.Λύτρα,Οδός Ν.Φωσκόλου,Οδός Νικολάου Λούβαρη,Οδός Νικολάου Φωσκόλου,Οδός Παναϊτίου Ναυάρχου,Οδός Σανταμούρη,Οδός Σκουφά,Οδός Ταξιαρχών,Οδός Τριών Ιεραρχών,Οδός Φραγκίσκου Παξιμάδη,Οδός Χρ.Γαρυφάλλου,Πάνορμος,Παλλάδα,Παραλία Ρόχαρι,Πλατεία Αγίου Χαραλάμπου,Πλατεία Ελευθερίας,Πλατεία Ορλώφ,Πλατεία Παντανάσσης,Πλατεία Ταξιαρχών,Πλατεία Φειδίου,Πλατεία Χατζηγεωργίου Σιώτη,Πλατιά,Πόρτο,Πύργος,Ράχη Χατζηράδου,Σκυλαντάρ,Σμαρδάκιτο,Στενή,Τριαντάρος,Τριπόταμος,Υστέρνια,Φαλατάδος,Χατζηράδος,οδός Λαζάρου Σώχου,οδός Μ.Νόρδεστρωμ,οδός Μ.Πλυτά,οδός Μάρκου Ψάρρου,οδός Ν.Λούβαρη,οδός Ναυάρχου Μιαούλη</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showType'>USER_SELECTED</b:widget-setting>
       <b:widget-setting name='showFreqNumbers'>false</b:widget-setting>
     </b:widget-settings>
     <b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title'>
</b:if>
<div class='listsearch-input-item'>
<div class='widget-content'>
<div class='listsearch-input-item'><i class='mbri-key single-i'/>
<select class='label1_test'>
<option>Επέλεξε τοποθεσία...</option>
<b:loop values='data:labels' var='label'>
<option expr:value='data:label.name'><data:label.name/>
(<data:label.count/>)
</option>
</b:loop>
</select>
  </div>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
    </div></div>
</b:includable>
   </b:widget>
 </b:section>
<script>
 //<![CDATA[ 
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.label1_test');
const selectElement2 = document.querySelector('.label2_test');


selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');
  result.textContent = `${event.target.value}`;
});

selectElement2.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result2 = document.querySelector('.result1');
  result2.textContent = `${event.target.value}`;
});



function redirectTo(){
     var parameter1 = document.querySelector('.result').innerText;
     var parameter2 = document.querySelector('.result1').innerText; // some thing like this you can set value for 2nd Param.


if (parameter1 == 0 && parameter2 == 0 ) {

window.location.href="";

}else if (parameter2 == 0 ) {

  window.location.href="/search/?q=label:"+parameter1;

}else if (parameter1 == 0){

    window.location.href="/search/?q=label:"+parameter2;

}else{
    window.location.href="/search/?q=label:"+parameter1+"%20label:"+parameter2;
  }
}
//]]>

            </script>


                                  <br></br>
<div class='result'/>
<div class='result1'/>

                                 <a class='button fs-map-btn' onclick="redirectTo();">Search....</a>
```

Comment: I have set conditions for cases that in the first or second dropdown, user didn't select an option....